# Number of configurations in a project for build and install

Tags: teamcity-8.0

In our project, we currently have two different configurations. The first one **builds** the assemblies. The other **packages** (including moving stuff to the right directories etc.) everything for InstallShield.

Now, we can't agree if it's better to move all the build steps into a single configuration and run it as  a whole chain or if it's better to keep the **build process** separate from **creating installation package**.

Googling results in guides on **how** to do that but not **in what way** to do that (and our confusion is mainly due to the architecture of the configurations' order). We'll be using a few steps from PowerShield in order to move a number of files between different directories due to certain local considerations. The total number of steps will land on 5 or less.

---

The suggestion that I have is the following three configurations. They run separately, independently and their build steps overlap (being super sets of each other, consecutively regarded).

1. Configuration **Build**.
2. Configuration **Build and test**.
3. Configuration **Build, test and package**.

The main point of my suggestion is that e.g. the step that compiles the software is implemented in **each** configuration (as opposed to reusing the artifacts from an independent run of other configuration).

Answer (score 1):

I would argue like this:

- if you ever need to perform just *one* of the two steps - then leave them as separate steps. 
  This gives you the flexibility to run one, or the other, or both steps. E.g. could it be that you need to just build the solution, but not create the final installation package? E.g. for local testing?
- However, if you **never ever** use one of the steps separately (you **always** run both together), then I'd probably just merge them together into one - having two separate steps doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Splendid! Would you be willing to check out the edit in my question. I clarified my suggestion. I didn't want to explain **my** proposal because I didn't want to bias the replies.